# Why avoiding TDD would help the garbage collector?

Tags: garbage-collection, stackexchange

In this article about the stack overflow website : [StackOverflow Update: 560M Pageviews a Month, 25 Servers, and It's All About Performance](http://highscalability.com/blog/2014/7/21/stackoverflow-update-560m-pageviews-a-month-25-servers-and-i.html), you can read this :

> **Garbage collection driven programming**. SO goes to great lengths to
>   reduce garbage collection costs, skipping practices like TDD, avoiding
>   layers of abstraction, and using static methods. While extreme, the
>   result is highly performing code.

I can see why avoiding layers of abstraction and static methods would prevent garbage-collecting, but I don't get why TDD would be harmful for it.

Answer (score 0):

TDD is about automatic testing, and in most cases code that can be automatically tested requires some layers of abstractions and interfaces.

Comment: Yeah, but these tests are only done once every deployment, I find it a little bit extreme to get rid of every tests just for the garbage collector's sake.

Comment: How often tests are done does not matter - what matters is additional mechanisms present in the code for testing purposes. I find it extreme too, and I think that if one needs to fight with garbage collection, maybe one should avoid a garbage-collected language in the first place.